# How to create custom controller in Laravel Voyager

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, voyager

I am very new in Voyager.

I have got all the controllers inside `TCG\\Voyager\\Http\\Controllers` while installing Voyager but didn't find other controllers those I have created using BREAD.

Besides that I want to create custom controller in my Voyager admin panel inside `App\\Http\\Controllers\\Voyager` . I also followed the steps of Voyager tutorial in Youtube for making custom controller, but couldn't create.

Anybody help please ?

Comment: Good day! Did you check this [link](https://voyager.readme.io/docs/using-custom-http-controllers)? About custom controller fo Voyager?

Comment: @ D. Erashkin ... No

Comment: @D.Erashkin... It doesn't work. Controller still doesn't create inside `App\Http\Voyager`

Comment: It wont create BREAD Controller automatically. When you create/edit BREAD for your model you can set Controller Name.

Comment: @D.Erashkin... Then can't I create custom controller in Voyager?

Comment: I think you need to create your custom BREAD Controller and you can create it based on Voyager's BREAD controller. (when you create BREAD for some you model, Voyager doesn't generate/create new Controllers. It uses VoyagerBreadController.php). Hope it will help you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your config\voyager.php file add your namespace:

```
'controllers' => [
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Back',
],
```

Then publish voyageres controllers to your namespace

```
php artisan voyager:controllers
```

Within that namespace create a new controller derived from VoyagerBreadController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Back;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SchoolController extends VoyagerBreadController
{
```

Then you can specify the controller in the bread editor.

NOTE: I did have to refer to mine as Back\SchoolController instead of just SchoolController as I would have expected.

[image: Setting controller on backend]

Comment: @FloatingKiwi......I have created controller manually in the namespace as you suggested. But how to specify the created controller in the bread editor ? Is it from `vendor\tcg\voyager\resources\views\bread\` ?

Comment: @raff - It's on the bread editor in the front end. https://localhost/admin/database/schools/bread/edit

Answer (score 3):

Update:
From version 1.1 now you need to extend `VoyagerBaseController` instead of `VoyagerBreadController`.

Comment: I have created that but when going to edit my new bread im getting Undefined variable: model_name (View: /var/www/html/myapp/vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/tools/bread/edit-add.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your model.

`use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;`

```
protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::addGlobalScope('order', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->orderBy('name', 'asc');
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

- composer dump-autoload
- php artisan cache:clear
- php artisan config:clear
- php artisan view:clear
- php artisan route:cache

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.