# Create Custom Controller Without Database Table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, voyager

I want to create a page in Laravel Voyager admin which doesn't require any database table (to validate a JSON schema). Only the admin user should be able to access this page. To set permissions for this page, I'm assuming I need to include this page in BREAD list. How can I achieve this?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48743770/how-to-create-custom-controller-in-laravel-voyager) to create a custom controller. But how do I include this controller in BREAD list (only 'Add page' as I am not saving anything)?