# Laravel Voyager add additional methods to a BREAD controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, voyager

I created a new database through Voyager admin and created BREAD for that table. Now I need to add additional methods to that controller.

I tried to create a custom controller by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48759367/1591338). But the default actions (CRUD) of the controllers are gone.

Without disturbing the existing functionalities of the BREAD I need to add a few more methods in that controller. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you missed to extend **voyager's default BREAD controller**. for example let say we want to extend a Controller for our Product Model. so we make a ProductController like :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class ProductController extends TCG\Voyager\Http\Controllers\VoyagerBaseController{

    //add more functions
}
```

good luck